# Input password in Bluetooth devices in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, password-encryption

I have made a connection between an Ionic/Angular app and some BluetoothLE devices.

The connection requirements due to docs https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle is only the address (no password)

But when I start reading data, the data that is encrypted is not available to read. So, if i do not include the password I wont be able to read those data. I mean that i need something like this (the image is from a bluetooth app in Play Store) but I don't know where to put the collected password.

[image: a]

After reading different service's values these are the results.

[image: b]

The connection:

```
$rootScope.connect = function(addressParam) {
  var params = {address: addressParam};

  $cordovaBluetoothLE.connect(params).then(null, function (obj) {
    console.log("Conexión error " + obj.status + " con dirección: " + obj.address);
    $rootScope.close(addressParam);
  }, function (obj) {
    console.log("Conexión success " + obj.status + " con dirección: " + obj.address);
    $rootScope.isCon(addressParam);
    if(obj.status==="disconnected" || obj.status==="undefined" ){
      $rootScope.connect(addressParam);
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks

PD: The devices that i'm connecting with are beacons.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean that i need something like this (the image is from a bluetooth
>   app in Play Store) but I don't know where to put the collected
>   password.

“Input Password” dialog will appear or not depend on IO Capabilities of two devices who want connect with each other. There are several methods used in pairing for Bluetooth LE devices. One of them is named “Passkey” that require user entry password in order to complete pair procedure. Another is named ”Just Works” that will be used where at least one of the devices does not have a display capable of displaying a six digit number nor does it have a keyboard capable of entering six decimal digits. 
If beacon device you are connecting doesn’t have the ability to display or communicate a 6 digit decimal number you will not be queried entry password.

> But when I start reading data, the data that is encrypted is not
>   available to read.

I saw you have already read some data.
Service(`UUID=0x1800` ) stand for Generic Access. Characteristic(`UUID=0x2a00`) stand for device name. Here device name is “`2-3`”. “`2`” in ASCII is `0x32` and “`-`” is `0x2D` and “`3`” is `0x33`.
Service(`UUID=0xfff0`) is undefined by Bluetooth officially. Maybe it is manufacturer specialized. If you want to parse these data you may need know these data structure that how they are organized. What other data do you want read? What's kind of these data?

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Those data is beacon's UUID. The identifier of the device. I already want to read fff3 and fff4 values, which are the major and minor. The gadget is from Jaalee. Can you think any way to make this possible with Ionic? I don't want to use native Android or iOS in order not to make two different apps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @aserrin55 I don't kown fff3 and fff4 are service UUID or Characteristic UUID. If they are service UUID you can get them by executing "Discover All Primary Services"( reference here [link](https://community.nxp.com/thread/332233)). While if they are Characteristics of Service(UUID=fff0)you can direct use fff3 or fff4 as UUID to read Characteristic after you get the fff0 service.

Comment: fff0 is the service UUID and fff3,fff4 are characteristics. How to do that on Cordova? What you are saying is form native? I'm not really a pro in this topic and i'am a little bit lost with you answer. Nevertheless, thank you so much. Hope you could explain a little.

Comment: @aserrin55 You can use `bluetoothle.read` method provided in Cordova([link](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#read)). It is `bluetoothle.read(readSuccess, readError, params);` . Here, for example, params is `{
  "address": "ECC037FD-72AE-AFC5-9213-CA785B3B5C63",
  "service": "fff0",
  "characteristic": "fff3"
}` Note:You need use your own address instead of above("ECC037FD-72AE-AFC5-9213-CA785B3B5C63") .This method read a particular service's characteristic once. So, for fff4, you need use "fff4" instead of "fff3" above and read once more.

Comment: I'm using that plugin and method but the results are encrypted ( look at the right photo). So i dont know what more to do

Comment: @aserrin55 You may try `bluetoothle.bond(bondSuccess, bondError, params);` before connection. This will start pairing procedure that will request passkey input.

Comment: That bond method does not require password ( in my case ). The status is always bonding and non bonded. I have implemented it too.

Comment: @aserrin55 Encryption is completed in pairing for Bluetooth and data Encrypted after pairing. So, I wonder how to judge the data is encrypted or not for you. Generally speaking, beacon data don't need Encryption because of it is designed to be public and Beacons themselves don’t include any sensitive information.

Comment: The fact is that the jaalee beacons that i'm using are surely password encrypted due to the official docs and my experience with the Jaalee Configuration App (eBeacon in Play Store). I know that the password is 666666 but I don't know where i shoud use it. There is no input to write neither while using my application.

Comment: You can try these steps:[How To Start To Use It](https://www.jaalee.com/support)

Step 1: Download the latest version eBeacon App(version 1.6.0) from Apple App store. 

Step 2:Open the Bluetooth and eBeacon App. 

**Step 3:Tap the Beacon for 3-5 times on hard surface, and the Beacon will be connectable when you hear a buzz.** 

**Step 4:Click the Beacon in the eBeacon App which you want to configure and enter the password to connect it.**

Step 5:Now, you can configure and use Jaalee Beacon normally.

Comment: That's true, is the app that i'm using. Instead of that, i want to create an app with those functionality with Ionic and its plugins, but it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding for Cordova is that it provides sort of a wrapper layer for “Androind” and “iOS” SDK, so as to have an universal API for both platforms.

As per the [cordova-plugin-bluetoothle](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) project, the low-level android and iOS implementations are done in [here](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle/tree/master/src/android) and [here](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle/tree/master/src/ios). However, it does not necessarily work with every ble device.

Fortunately, Jaalee Beacon have their iOS SDK hosted in [here](https://github.com/jaalee/Jaalee-Beacon-iOS-SDK-master)(the implementation does not look open sourced to me though), and android SDK in [here](https://github.com/jaalee/Jaalee-Beacon-Android-SDK-master). What we probably need to do is to **port** or **modify** the low level implementations for the [cordova-plugin-bluetoothle](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) driver classes, respectively. Otherwise, I don’t see everything to work perfectly with the jaalee beacon.

As per the password input, it’s not being used when connecting to the ble device, it only gets used when reading/writing the ble characteristics. You can check out this [file](https://github.com/jaalee/Jaalee-Beacon-Android-SDK-master/blob/master/src/com/jaalee/sdk/connection/BeaconConnection.java) line 143 ~ 159. Note where the password is being used.

So, it’s OK to have a hard-coded value(aka 0x666666) in your cordova code.

I did not read the source code thoroughly, but I suggest you do so. Hopefully you can get something useful.